# How to run a variable's output through ssh in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to run an Alias in Destination Server which the alias name is `$VAR`. I used this line in my script:

```
ssh -o Loglevel=QUIET -t user@192.168.x.x /bin/bash -ic '$VAR'
```

`$VAR` alias will run another script in the destination server.

But the output of my script is:

> /bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument.

Can anybody help me how can I run output of a variable in SSH command?

Comment: Where is `$VAR` defined? If on the local side, then you need to change your single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `'$VAR' ` is not resolving to its value since its in a single quote. Remove the quote and its should work fine.

Comment: @GovindKailas: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/3776858)

Comment: Thank you guys, that was my fault. Double quote helps.